# Perform S/MIME signing and checking signature immediately afterwards fails

Tags: java, cryptography, jakarta-mail, bouncycastle

The following source is a JUnit-Test that shows the problem in question.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name;
import org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.Extension;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.X509v3CertificateBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509CertificateConverter;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509ExtensionUtils;
import org.bouncycastle.cert.jcajce.JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInfoGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformationVerifier;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JcaSimpleSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.cms.jcajce.JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.SMIMESigned;
import org.bouncycastle.mail.smime.SMIMESignedGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

/**
 * Test class to check out S/MIME signature and verification
 */
public class __Run_SMIMESigning extends TestCase {
    final static SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    }

    /**
     * Tests the issue
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public void testMailSigning() throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
        kpg.initialize(1024, random);

        KeyPair aliceKey = kpg.generateKeyPair();
        X509Certificate aliceCert = makeCertificate(aliceKey, "CN=Alice's Certiicate", aliceKey, "CN=Alice's Certiicate");

        MimeBodyPart mbp = createMailBodyPart();
        mbp.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();

        SMIMESignedGenerator gen = new SMIMESignedGenerator();
        JcaSimpleSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder builder = new JcaSimpleSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder().setProvider("BC");
        SignerInfoGenerator sigGen = builder.build("SHA256WithRSA", aliceKey.getPrivate(), aliceCert);
        gen.addSignerInfoGenerator(sigGen);

        MimeMultipart signedMM = gen.generate(mbp);
        MimeBodyPart signedBody = new MimeBodyPart();
        signedBody.setContent(signedMM, signedMM.getContentType());

        System.out.println("signed:");
        signedBody.writeTo(System.out);
        System.out.println();

        MimeMultipart content = (MimeMultipart) signedBody.getContent();
        SMIMESigned sig = new SMIMESigned(content);
        SignerInformation si = sig.getSignerInfos().getSigners().iterator().next();
        SignerInformationVerifier verifier = new JcaSimpleSignerInfoVerifierBuilder().setProvider("BC").build(aliceCert);
        System.out.println("verified: " + si.verify(verifier));
    }

    private MimeBodyPart createMailBodyPart() throws MessagingException {
        MimeBodyPart plainText = new MimeBodyPart();
        plainText.setText("Plain text with non-ascii: €", "utf8", "plain");
        MimeBodyPart htmlText = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlText.setText("<h1>Some HTML</h1><p>Some text with non-ascii: €</p>", "utf8", "html");

        MimeBodyPart alternatives = new MimeBodyPart();
        alternatives.setContent(new MimeMultipart("alternative", plainText, htmlText));

        MimeBodyPart textAttachment = new MimeBodyPart();
        textAttachment.setText("some attachment data containing non-ascii-data like €", "utf8", "plain");
        textAttachment.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
        textAttachment.setDisposition("attachment");
        textAttachment.setFileName("filename.txt");

        MimeBodyPart ret = new MimeBodyPart();
        ret.setContent(new MimeMultipart(alternatives, textAttachment));
        return ret;
    }

    // taken from the BC test case class
    // at https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/mail/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/examples/CreateSignedMultipartMail.java
    static X509Certificate makeCertificate(
            KeyPair subKP,
            String  subDN,
            KeyPair issKP,
            String  issDN)
            throws Exception
        {
            PublicKey  subPub  = subKP.getPublic();
            PrivateKey issPriv = issKP.getPrivate();
            PublicKey  issPub  = issKP.getPublic();

            JcaX509ExtensionUtils extUtils = new JcaX509ExtensionUtils();
            X509v3CertificateBuilder v3CertGen = new JcaX509v3CertificateBuilder(new X500Name(issDN), BigInteger.valueOf(random.nextLong()), new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()), new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (1000L * 60 * 60 * 24 * 100)), new X500Name(subDN), subPub);

            v3CertGen.addExtension(
                    Extension.subjectKeyIdentifier,
                false,
                extUtils.createSubjectKeyIdentifier(subPub));

            v3CertGen.addExtension(
                    Extension.authorityKeyIdentifier,
                false,
                extUtils.createAuthorityKeyIdentifier(issPub));

            return new JcaX509CertificateConverter().setProvider("BC").getCertificate(v3CertGen.build(new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA256withRSA").setProvider("BC").build(issPriv)));
    }
}
```

I'm creating a mail that is typical today:

- multipart/mixed

  - multipart/alternative

    - text/plain mail body
    - text/html mail body
  - text/plain attachment with filename

I then use BouncyCastle to sign the whole thing. When I try to verify the signature immediately afterwards, it fails with the exception

```
org.bouncycastle.cms.CMSSignerDigestMismatchException: message-digest attribute value does not match calculated value
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation.doVerify(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.cms.SignerInformation.verify(Unknown Source)
    at __Run_SMIMESigning.testMailSigning(__Run_SMIMESigning.java:77)
```

If I compress the multipart mime body before signing, the verification succeeds, so I think that my way of doing the signing should be correct in principle but I'm out of ideas what to do to get this particular use case to work.

My first test was done with BouncyCastle 1.54 but 1.62 (the current version) shows no difference in the result.